# Getting product stock quantity isn't working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On single product page I'm trying to get stock quantity or atleast stock status from woocommerce product but it seems not working properly, even if it's simple product (manage stock status is checked) or variable product the button is not showing. And strange thing happens - I've got Yith Product Bundle plugin and even if every item is in stock it shows that button but whatever, that's not main problem.

So here is code I'm using

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'show_wishlist');
 
function show_wishlist() {
    global $product;
    $stockQ=$product->get_stock_quantity();
 
    if ( $stockQ < 1 ) {
        echo "<button>Hello</button>";
    }
}
```

I've also tried but completely nothing happens.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'show_wishlist');
 
function show_wishlist() {
    global $product;
 
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        echo "<button>Hello</button>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First check if the hook is firing properly.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'show_wishlist' );

function show_wishlist(){
    echo '<p>Some custom text before</p>';
}
```

If you are able to confirm that the hook is working then use the below code.

```
    function show_wishlist() {
        global $product;
        // Change In Stock Text
        if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_in_stock() ) {
    //add your code here for Products in Stock
    }
else{
//add your code here for Products out of Stock
}
    }
```

Comment: Ooh, I've just checked if the hook is firing properly, well it is but only on products that are available in stock but it's not firing on products that are out of stock (and I want to fire function on products that are out of stock). So it looks like I should use different hook.

Comment: Why do you want to check stock on out of stock products? You can just add an else part to the above If condition and do what you want. I have updated my answer and added else part. Do accept the answer if it answers the question